# Html page is displayed well as file, but not on server

Tags: html, wamp

I have a really weird problem: a HTML page is displayed properly if I access it in my browser by path, however it looks awful if I access it from my localhost. I know this is a very large topic, but what could be the cause of something like that? I am using WampServer. I tried this in chrome, Firefox and IE and the result is the same. I can provide the source code if needed, however it is very large (700 lines the main code, plus a lot of dependencies).

I just want to know if there is an usual reason that might provoke this behaviour

Via path:[image: The file via path]
Via server:[image: The file via server]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Calendar</title>

<!-- Include CSS for JQuery Frontier Calendar plugin (Required for calendar plugin) -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/frontierCalendar/jquery-frontier-cal-1.3.2.css" />

<!-- Include CSS for color picker plugin (Not required for calendar plugin. Used for example.) -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/colorpicker/colorpicker.css" />

<!-- Include CSS for JQuery UI (Required for calendar plugin.) -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery-ui/smoothness/jquery-ui-1.8.1.custom.css" />

<!--
Include JQuery Core (Required for calendar plugin)
** This is our IE fix version which enables drag-and-drop to work correctly in IE. See README file in js/jquery-core folder. **
-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-core/jquery-1.4.2-ie-fix.min.js"></script>

<!-- Include JQuery UI (Required for calendar plugin.) -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui/smoothness/jquery-ui-1.8.1.custom.min.js"></script>

<!-- Include color picker plugin (Not required for calendar plu gin. Used for example.) -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/colorpicker/colorpicker.js"></script>

<!-- Include jquery tooltip plugin (Not required for calendar plugin. Used for example.) -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-qtip-1.0.0-rc3140944/jquery.qtip-1.0.js"></script>

<!--
    (Required for plugin)
    Dependancies for JQuery Frontier Calendar plugin.
    ** THESE MUST BE INCLUDED BEFORE THE FRONTIER CALENDAR PLUGIN. **
-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/lib/jshashtable-2.1.js"></script>

<!-- Include JQuery Frontier Calendar plugin -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/frontierCalendar/jquery-frontier-cal-1.3.2.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body style="background: url(background.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;">

<!-- Some CSS for our example. (Not required for calendar plugin. Used for example.)-->
<style type="text/css" media="screen">
/*
Default font-size on the default ThemeRoller theme is set in ems, and with a value that when combined 
with body { font-size: 62.5%; } will align pixels with ems, so 11px=1.1em, 14px=1.4em. If setting the 
body font-size to 62.5% isn't an option, or not one you want, you can set the font-size in ThemeRoller 
to 1em or set it to px.
http://osdir.com/ml/jquery-ui/2009-04/msg00071.html
*/
body { 
    font-size: 62.5%; 

}
#mycal {
    opacity:0.9;
}
.shadow {
    -moz-box-shadow: 3px 3px 4px #aaaaaa;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 3px 4px #aaaaaa;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 4px #aaaaaa;
    /* For IE 8 */
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Strength=4, Direction=135, Color='#aaaaaa')";
    /* For IE 5.5 - 7 */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Strength=4, Direction=135, Color='#aaaaaa');
}
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){   

    var clickDate = "";
    var clickAgendaItem = "";

    /**
     * Initializes calendar with current year & month
     * specifies the callbacks for day click & agenda item click events
     * then returns instance of plugin object
     */
    var jfcalplugin = $("#mycal").jFrontierCal({
        date: new Date(),
        dayClickCallback: myDayClickHandler,
        agendaClickCallback: myAgendaClickHandler,
        agendaDropCallback: myAgendaDropHandler,
        agendaMouseoverCallback: myAgendaMouseoverHandler,
        applyAgendaTooltipCallback: myApplyTooltip,
        agendaDragStartCallback : myAgendaDragStart,
        agendaDragStopCallback : myAgendaDragStop,
        dragAndDropEnabled: true
    }).data("plugin");

    /**
     * Do something when dragging starts on agenda div
     */
    function myAgendaDragStart(eventObj,divElm,agendaItem){
        // destroy our qtip tooltip
        if(divElm.data("qtip")){
            divElm.qtip("destroy");
        }   
    };

    /**
     * Do something when dragging stops on agenda div
     */
    function myAgendaDragStop(eventObj,divElm,agendaItem){
        //alert("drag stop");
    };
    0
    /**
     * Custom tooltip - use any tooltip library you want to display the agenda data.
     * for this example we use qTip - http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/
     *
     * @param divElm - jquery object for agenda div element
     * @param agendaItem - javascript object containing agenda data.
     */
    function myApplyTooltip(divElm,agendaItem){

        // Destroy currrent tooltip if present
        if(divElm.data("qtip")){
            divElm.qtip("destroy");
        }

        var displayData = "";

        var title = agendaItem.title;
        var startDate = agendaItem.startDate;
        var endDate = agendaItem.startDate;
        var allDay = agendaItem.allDay;
        var data = agendaItem.data;
        displayData += "<br><b>" + title+ "</b><br><br>";
        if(allDay){
            displayData += "(All day event)<br><br>";
        }else{
            displayData += "<b>Starts:</b> " + startDate + "<br>" + "<b>Ends:</b> " + endDate + "<br><br>";
        }
        for (var propertyName in data) {
            displayData += "<b>" + propertyName + ":</b> " + data[propertyName] + "<br>"
        }
        // use the user specified colors from the agenda item.
        var backgroundColor = agendaItem.displayProp.backgroundColor;
        var foregroundColor = agendaItem.displayProp.foregroundColor;
        var myStyle = {
            border: {
                width: 5,
                radius: 10
            },
            padding: 10, 
            textAlign: "left",
            tip: true,
            name: "dark" // other style properties are inherited from dark theme        
        };
        if(backgroundColor != null && backgroundColor != ""){
            myStyle["backgroundColor"] = backgroundColor;
        }
        if(foregroundColor != null && foregroundColor != ""){
            myStyle["color"] = foregroundColor;
        }
        // apply tooltip
        divElm.qtip({
            content: displayData,
            position: {
                corner: {
                    tooltip: "bottomMiddle",
                    target: "topMiddle"         
                },
                adjust: { 
                    mouse: true,
                    x: 0,
                    y: -15
                },
                target: "mouse"
            },
            show: { 
                when: { 
                    event: 'mouseover'
                }
            },
            style: myStyle
        });

    };

    /**
     * Make the day cells roughly 3/4th as tall as they are wide. this makes our calendar wider than it is tall. 
     */
    jfcalplugin.setAspectRatio("#mycal",0.75);

    /**
     * Called when user clicks day cell
     * use reference to plugin object to add agenda item
     */
    function myDayClickHandler(eventObj){
        // Get the Date of the day that was clicked from the event object
        var date = eventObj.data.calDayDate;
        // store date in our global js variable for access later
        clickDate = date.getFullYear() + "-" + (date.getMonth()+1) + "-" + date.getDate();
        // open our add event dialog
        $('#add-event-form').dialog('open');
    };

    /**
     * Called when user clicks and agenda item
     * use reference to plugin object to edit agenda item
     */
    function myAgendaClickHandler(eventObj){
        // Get ID of the agenda item from the event object
        var agendaId = eventObj.data.agendaId;      
        // pull agenda item from calendar
        var agendaItem = jfcalplugin.getAgendaItemById("#mycal",agendaId);
        clickAgendaItem = agendaItem;
        $("#display-event-form").dialog('open');
    };

    /**
     * Called when user drops an agenda item into a day cell.
     */
    function myAgendaDropHandler(eventObj){
        // Get ID of the agenda item from the event object
        var agendaId = eventObj.data.agendaId;
        // date agenda item was dropped onto
        var date = eventObj.data.calDayDate;
        // Pull agenda item from calendar
        var agendaItem = jfcalplugin.getAgendaItemById("#mycal",agendaId);      
        alert("You dropped agenda item " + agendaItem.title + 
            " onto " + date.toString() + ". Here is where you can make an AJAX call to update your database.");
    };

    /**
     * Called when a user mouses over an agenda item    
     */
    function myAgendaMouseoverHandler(eventObj){
        var agendaId = eventObj.data.agendaId;
        var agendaItem = jfcalplugin.getAgendaItemById("#mycal",agendaId);
        //alert("You moused over agenda item " + agendaItem.title + " at location (X=" + eventObj.pageX + ", Y=" + eventObj.pageY + ")");
    };
    /**
     * Initialize jquery ui datepicker. set date format to yyyy-mm-dd for easy parsing
     */
    $("#dateSelect").datepicker({
        showOtherMonths: true,
        selectOtherMonths: true,
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        showButtonPanel: true,
        dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'
    });

    /**
     * Set datepicker to current date
     */
    $("#dateSelect").datepicker('setDate', new Date());
    /**
     * Use reference to plugin object to a specific year/month
     */
    $("#dateSelect").bind('change', function() {
        var selectedDate = $("#dateSelect").val();
        var dtArray = selectedDate.split("-");
        var year = dtArray[0];
        // jquery datepicker months start at 1 (1=January)      
        var month = dtArray[1];
        // strip any preceeding 0's     
        month = month.replace(/^[0]+/g,"")      
        var day = dtArray[2];
        // plugin uses 0-based months so we subtrac 1
        jfcalplugin.showMonth("#mycal",year,parseInt(month-1).toString());
    }); 
    /**
     * Initialize previous month button
     */
    $("#BtnPreviousMonth").button();
    $("#BtnPreviousMonth").click(function() {
        jfcalplugin.showPreviousMonth("#mycal");
        // update the jQuery datepicker value
        var calDate = jfcalplugin.getCurrentDate("#mycal"); // returns Date object
        var cyear = calDate.getFullYear();
        // Date month 0-based (0=January)
        var cmonth = calDate.getMonth();
        var cday = calDate.getDate();
        // jquery datepicker month starts at 1 (1=January) so we add 1
        $("#dateSelect").datepicker("setDate",cyear+"-"+(cmonth+1)+"-"+cday);
        return false;
    });
    /**
     * Initialize next month button
     */
    $("#BtnNextMonth").button();
    $("#BtnNextMonth").click(function() {
        jfcalplugin.showNextMonth("#mycal");
        // update the jQuery datepicker value
        var calDate = jfcalplugin.getCurrentDate("#mycal"); // returns Date object
        var cyear = calDate.getFullYear();
        // Date month 0-based (0=January)
        var cmonth = calDate.getMonth();
        var cday = calDate.getDate();
        // jquery datepicker month starts at 1 (1=January) so we add 1
        $("#dateSelect").datepicker("setDate",cyear+"-"+(cmonth+1)+"-"+cday);       
        return false;
    });

    /**
     * Initialize delete all agenda items button
     */
    $("#BtnDeleteAll").button();
    $("#BtnDeleteAll").click(function() {   
        jfcalplugin.deleteAllAgendaItems("#mycal"); 
        return false;
    });     

    /**
     * Initialize add event modal form
     */
    $("#add-event-form").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        height: 400,
        width: 400,
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            'Add Event': function() {

                var what = jQuery.trim($("#what").val());

                if(what == ""){
                    alert("Please enter a short event description into the \"what\" field.");
                }else{

                    var startDate = $("#startDate").val();
                    var startDtArray = startDate.split("-");
                    var startYear = startDtArray[0];
                    // jquery datepicker months start at 1 (1=January)      
                    var startMonth = startDtArray[1];       
                    var startDay = startDtArray[2];
                    // strip any preceeding 0's     
                    startMonth = startMonth.replace(/^[0]+/g,"");
                    startDay = startDay.replace(/^[0]+/g,"");
                    var startHour = jQuery.trim($("#startHour").val());
                    var startMin = jQuery.trim($("#startMin").val());
                    var startMeridiem = jQuery.trim($("#startMeridiem").val());
                    startHour = parseInt(startHour.replace(/^[0]+/g,""));
                    if(startMin == "0" || startMin == "00"){
                        startMin = 0;
                    }else{
                        startMin = parseInt(startMin.replace(/^[0]+/g,""));
                    }
                    if(startMeridiem == "AM" && startHour == 12){
                        startHour = 0;
                    }else if(startMeridiem == "PM" && startHour < 12){
                        startHour = parseInt(startHour) + 12;
                    }

                    var endDate = $("#startDate").val();
                    var endDtArray = endDate.split("-");
                    var endYear = endDtArray[0];
                    // jquery datepicker months start at 1 (1=January)      
                    var endMonth = endDtArray[1];       
                    var endDay = endDtArray[2];
                    // strip any preceeding 0's     
                    endMonth = endMonth.replace(/^[0]+/g,"");

                    endDay = endDay.replace(/^[0]+/g,"");
                    var endHour = jQuery.trim($("#startHour").val());
                    var endMin = jQuery.trim($("#startMin").val());
                    var endMeridiem = jQuery.trim($("#startMeridiem").val());
                    endHour = parseInt(endHour.replace(/^[0]+/g,""));
                    if(endMin == "0" || endMin == "00"){
                        endMin = 0;
                    }else{
                        endMin = parseInt(endMin.replace(/^[0]+/g,""));
                    }
                    if(endMeridiem == "AM" && endHour == 12){
                        endHour = 0;
                    }else if(endMeridiem == "PM" && endHour < 12){
                        endHour = parseInt(endHour) + 12;
                    }

                    //alert("Start time: " + startHour + ":" + startMin + " " + startMeridiem + ", End time: " + endHour + ":" + endMin + " " + endMeridiem);

                    // Dates use integers
                    var startDateObj = new Date(parseInt(startYear),parseInt(startMonth)-1,parseInt(startDay),startHour,startMin,0,0);
                    var endDateObj = new Date(parseInt(startYear),parseInt(startMonth)-1,parseInt(startDay),startHour,startMin,0,0);

                    // add new event to the calendar
                    jfcalplugin.addAgendaItem(
                        "#mycal",
                        what,
                        startDateObj,
                        endDateObj,
                        false,
                        {
                            fname: "Santa",
                            lname: "Claus",
                            leadReindeer: "Rudolph",
                            myDate: new Date(),
                            myNum: 42
                        },
                        {
                            backgroundColor: $("#colorBackground").val(),
                            foregroundColor: $("#colorForeground").val()
                        }
                    );

                    $(this).dialog('close');

                }

            },
            Cancel: function() {
                $(this).dialog('close');
            }
        },
        open: function(event, ui){
            // initialize start date picker
            $("#startDate").datepicker({
                showOtherMonths: true,
                selectOtherMonths: true,
                changeMonth: true,
                changeYear: true,
                showButtonPanel: true,
                dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'
            });
            // initialize end date picker
/*          $("#endDate").datepicker({
                showOtherMonths: true,
                selectOtherMonths: true,
                changeMonth: true,
                changeYear: true,
                showButtonPanel: true,
                dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'
            });*/
            // initialize with the date that was clicked
            $("#startDate").val(clickDate);
            $("#endDate").val(clickDate);
            // initialize color pickers
            $("#colorSelectorBackground").ColorPicker({
                color: "#333333",
                onShow: function (colpkr) {
                    $(colpkr).css("z-index","10000");
                    $(colpkr).fadeIn(500);
                    return false;
                },
                onHide: function (colpkr) {
                    $(colpkr).fadeOut(500);
                    return false;
                },
                onChange: function (hsb, hex, rgb) {
                    $("#colorSelectorBackground div").css("backgroundColor", "#" + hex);
                    $("#colorBackground").val("#" + hex);
                }
            });
            //$("#colorBackground").val("#1040b0");     
            $("#colorSelectorForeground").ColorPicker({
                color: "#ffffff",
                onShow: function (colpkr) {
                    $(colpkr).css("z-index","10000");
                    $(colpkr).fadeIn(500);
                    return false;
                },
                onHide: function (colpkr) {
                    $(colpkr).fadeOut(500);
                    return false;
                },
                onChange: function (hsb, hex, rgb) {
                    $("#colorSelectorForeground div").css("backgroundColor", "#" + hex);
                    $("#colorForeground").val("#" + hex);
                }
            });
            //$("#colorForeground").val("#ffffff");             
            // put focus on first form input element
            $("#what").focus();
        },
        close: function() {
            // reset form elements when we close so they are fresh when the dialog is opened again.
            $("#startDate").datepicker("destroy");
            $("#endDate").datepicker("destroy");
            $("#startDate").val("");
            $("#endDate").val("");
            $("#startHour option:eq(0)").attr("selected", "selected");
            $("#startMin option:eq(0)").attr("selected", "selected");
            $("#startMeridiem option:eq(0)").attr("selected", "selected");
            $("#endHour option:eq(0)").attr("selected", "selected");
            $("#endMin option:eq(0)").attr("selected", "selected");
            $("#endMeridiem option:eq(0)").attr("selected", "selected");            
            $("#what").val("");
            //$("#colorBackground").val("#1040b0");
            //$("#colorForeground").val("#ffffff");
        }
    });

    /**
     * Initialize display event form.
     */
    $("#display-event-form").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        height: 400,
        width: 400,
        modal: true,
        buttons: {      
            Cancel: function() {
                $(this).dialog('close');
            },
            'Edit': function() {
                alert("Make your own edit screen or dialog!");
            },
            'Delete': function() {
                if(confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this agenda item?")){
                    if(clickAgendaItem != null){
                        jfcalplugin.deleteAgendaItemById("#mycal",clickAgendaItem.agendaId);
                        //jfcalplugin.deleteAgendaItemByDataAttr("#mycal","myNum",42);
                    }
                    $(this).dialog('close');
                }
            }           
        },
        open: function(event, ui){
            if(clickAgendaItem != null){
                var title = clickAgendaItem.title;
                var startDate = clickAgendaItem.startDate;
                var endDate = clickAgendaItem.endDate;
                var allDay = clickAgendaItem.allDay;
                var data = clickAgendaItem.data;
                // in our example add agenda modal form we put some fake data in the agenda data. we can retrieve it here.
                $("#display-event-form").append(
                    "<br><b>" + title+ "</b><br><br>"       
                );              
                if(allDay){
                    $("#display-event-form").append(
                        "(All day event)<br><br>"               
                    );              
                }else{
                    $("#display-event-form").append(
                        "<b>Starts:</b> " + startDate + "<br>" +
                        "<b>Ends:</b> " + endDate + "<br><br>"              
                    );              
                }
                for (var propertyName in data) {
                    $("#display-event-form").append("<b>" + propertyName + ":</b> " + data[propertyName] + "<br>");
                }           
            }       
        },
        close: function() {
            // clear agenda data
            $("#display-event-form").html("");
        }
    });  

    /**
     * Initialize our tabs
     */
    $("#tabs").tabs({
        /*
         * Our calendar is initialized in a closed tab so we need to resize it when the example tab opens.
         */
        show: function(event, ui){
            if(ui.index == 1){
                jfcalplugin.doResize("#mycal");
            }
        }   
    });

});
</script>
    <div id="tabs-2">
        <div id="example" style="margin: auto; width:80%;">
        <div id="toolbar" class="ui-widget-header ui-corner-all" style="padding:3px; vertical-align: middle; white-space:nowrap; overflow: hidden;">
            <button id="BtnPreviousMonth">Previous Month</button>
            <button id="BtnNextMonth">Next Month</button>
            Date: <input type="text" id="dateSelect" size="20"/>
            <button id="BtnDeleteAll">Delete All</button>
        </div>

        <br>

        <!--
        You can use pixel widths or percentages. Calendar will auto resize all sub elements.
        Height will be calculated by aspect ratio. Basically all day cells will be as tall
        as they are wide.
        -->
        <div id="mycal"></div>

        </div>

        <!-- debugging-->
        <div id="calDebug"></div>

        <!-- Add event modal form -->
        <style type="text/css">
            //label, input.text, select { display:block; }
            fieldset { padding:0; border:0; margin-top:25px; }
            .ui-dialog .ui-state-error { padding: .3em; }
            .validateTips { border: 1px solid transparent; padding: 0.3em; }
        </style>
        <div id="add-event-form" title="Add New Event">
            <p class="validateTips">All form fields are required.</p>
            <form>
            <fieldset>
                <label for="name">What?</label>
                <input type="text" name="what" id="what" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" style="margin-bottom:12px; width:95%; padding: .4em;"/>
                <table style="width:100%; padding:5px;">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <label>Start Date</label>
                            <input type="text" name="startDate" id="startDate" value="" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" style="margin-bottom:12px; width:95%; padding: .4em;"/>                
                        </td>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                        <td>
                            <label>Start Hour</label>
                            <select id="startHour" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" style="margin-bottom:12px; width:95%; padding: .4em;">
                                <option value="12" SELECTED>12</option>
                                <option value="1">1</option>
                                <option value="2">2</option>
                                <option value="3">3</option>
                                <option value="4">4</option>
                                <option value="5">5</option>
                                <option value="6">6</option>
                                <option value="7">7</option>
                                <option value="8">8</option>
                                <option value="9">9</option>
                                <option value="10">10</option>
                                <option value="11">11</option>
                            </select>               
                        <td>
                        <td>
                            <label>Start Minute</label>
                            <select id="startMin" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" style="margin-bottom:12px; width:95%; padding: .4em;">
                                <option value="00" SELECTED>00</option>
                                <option value="10">10</option>
                                <option value="20">20</option>
                                <option value="30">30</option>
                                <option value="40">40</option>
                                <option value="50">50</option>
                            </select>               
                        <td>
                        <td>
                            <label>Start AM/PM</label>
                            <select id="startMeridiem" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" style="margin-bottom:12px; width:95%; padding: .4em;">
                                <option value="AM" SELECTED>AM</option>
                                <option value="PM">PM</option>
                            </select>               
                        </td>
                    </tr>
<!--                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <label>End Date</label>
                            <input type="text" name="endDate" id="endDate" value="" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" style="margin-bottom:12px; width:95%; padding: .4em;"/>                
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <label>End Hour</label>
                            <select id="endHour" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" style="margin-bottom:12px; width:95%; padding: .4em;">
                                <option value="12" SELECTED>12</option>
                                <option value="1">1</option>
                                <option value="2">2</option>
                                <option value="3">3</option>
                                <option value="4">4</option>
                                <option value="5">5</option>
                                <option value="6">6</option>
                                <option value="7">7</option>
                                <option value="8">8</option>
                                <option value="9">9</option>
                                <option value="10">10</option>
                                <option value="11">11</option>
                            </select>               
                        <td>
                        <td>
                            <label>End Minute</label>
                            <select id="endMin" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" style="margin-bottom:12px; width:95%; padding: .4em;">
                                <option value="00" SELECTED>00</option>
                                <option value="10">10</option>
                                <option value="20">20</option>
                                <option value="30">30</option>
                                <option value="40">40</option>
                                <option value="50">50</option>
                            </select>               
                        <td>
                        <td>
                            <label>End AM/PM</label>
                            <select id="endMeridiem" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" style="margin-bottom:12px; width:95%; padding: .4em;">
                                <option value="AM" SELECTED>AM</option>
                                <option value="PM">PM</option>
                            </select>               
                        </td>               
                    </tr>-->            
                </table>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <label>Background Color</label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <div id="colorSelectorBackground"><div style="background-color: #333333; width:30px; height:30px; border: 2px solid #000000;"></div></div>
                            <input type="hidden" id="colorBackground" value="#333333">
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <label>Text Color</label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <div id="colorSelectorForeground"><div style="background-color: #ffffff; width:30px; height:30px; border: 2px solid #000000;"></div></div>
                            <input type="hidden" id="colorForeground" value="#ffffff">
                        </td>                       
                    </tr>               
                </table>
            </fieldset>
            </form>
        </div>

        <div id="display-event-form" title="View Agenda Item">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Entire folder: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/8awy5jxzttlq2vz/t1zH5XvgnH

Comment: can you supply screenshots of the 2 different websites?

Comment: is it plain html? a server based website (*.php) would certainly look different on a server

Comment: I thought about this, but it is just html, css and javascript

Comment: did you check the paths in your html? are all the files where they should be?

Comment: I think you should provide source code to help us understand the problem.

Comment: I added the source code

Comment: And where are linked JS, CSS files? Currently it is only a blank document.

Comment: I also added now the entire folder on my drobbox: I provided the link

Comment: I am having no problem in my PC. I have also wrote an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I afraid to say but your site is loading properly in my PC both with WAMP and without WAMP. So, the possible problem may be your browser or WAMP. There are few things you can try to solve this problem

- Clearing browser cache
- Try using different browser or a different version of existing one.
- Checking if .htacess is messing with your site. Try disabling it for a while.
- If you are using WAMP with very old configuration, get a new one with latest configuration.

Comment: yeah, I both cleared the cache and disabled .htaccess. Thanks so much!

Comment: You're welcome. Sometime small things make real big problems.

Answer (score 1):

Your paths are set wrong. I copypasted your code and it looked exactly like your "localhost" screenshot. As I only have the code, and no css/js/etc files that is only normal. Thus on your machine the paths must be set wrong. Try putting all your dependencies in your server's root directory and calling them via "/path". If nothing works, try using online files, you cannot set the path wrong there (i.e. instead of js/jquery-ui/jquery-1.9.1.js use http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js).

Comment: I also provided the folder. I will try changing my paths

Answer (score 0):

If you look at a website in your browser by path it will not be interpreted by your local apache server.

So php would be visible if you open it via path but it will be compiled when you use localhost. So it looks like something is interpreted that doesn't look like it should

Comment: that was my thought too, but he said that the problem is "a HTML page". no interpretation done there...

Comment: I thought about it, but it's just html, css and javascript

Comment: I guessed he uses php since he runs the wampserver which is pointless in a html only site. Otherwise it would be indeed a strange behavior for the website

Comment: @user2425234 I will need php in further development, I know it is useless for now. I will need to bind the calendar to a database, but for now, I already have a problem

Answer (score 0):

How is the page in server not showed properly? what lose (images, style, files, all)?

It can be because the dependencies are not configured properly to load from the server, you maybe need check the paths.

Also can be because there are things that are not being procesed by the server (dinamyc stuff).. if you can specify a little more your problem we can help more.

Comment: Okay, I tried to inspect it with firebug and now, it becomes really strange.
The "via server" version has 3 errors in the dependencies

Comment: What kind of errors are firebug showing? the images looks like the server it's not founding something. Add the errors to know it there are lost paths.

Comment: the errors are not about lost paths, there seem to be errors in the dependencies (but this happens only when displaying from server).
one error is some invalid character, another is "undefined element hashtable" and another is 'jfrontiercal not defined' (jfrontiercal is a plugin i use)

Comment: Had you checked if jfrontiercal is loading properly (i imagine that plugin is on charge of load the calendar)? check the net tab to watch if there is something that is not loading (marked with red).