# Html page of frontier calendar is displayed well as file, but not on django 1.6 server

Tags: jquery, django, calendar

I have a problem:a HTML page is displayed properly if I access it in my browser by path, however it looks awful if I access it from my localhost.  I am using Django Server. I tried this in chrome, ,mozilla  and the result is the same.

My question is almost same as this below mentioned question of SO but his query is for php and WAMP server but i need for python 2.7 and django 1.6 please guide me on this.

You can ref Screenshots in below mentioned question only.

[Html page is displayed well as file, but not on server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17724909/html-page-is-displayed-well-as-file-but-not-on-server)

Comment: django server ? tell us how you configured your static_root and templates files/..

Comment: there is no static_root in settings.py.

Comment: so i assume that you app running perfectly fine in development. Then in production environment is not working as you expected ?

Comment: you should follow the checklist.!

Comment: i will ans about that

Answer (score 0):

For in production environment you should follow [Deployment checklist](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/deployment/checklist/)

So by your question i assume that `STATIC_ROOT` are empty.

> Static files are automatically served by the development server. In production, you must define a STATIC_ROOT directory where collectstatic will copy them.